# return the latest monthly amount in the cost column

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

In column J I want a formula to return the cell value where the column heading is COST and the cell value under the COST column heading is >0.  This is a utility accrual and I am looking for the 'last' received bill to estimate the future accrual.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your Table is always like your picture you can write in J3 `=IF(N3>0,N3,Q3)`

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have mentioned because of the way the data in constantly loaded If, then, else statements could work but not preferred. Any thoughts on match, index or simple lookups?  With the dates the number is always going to be >0 but < 30,000.